# Python Unable to place the module

Tags: python, module, nameerror

I have just started learning python version 3 and trying to  create a file in python.
I placed the file in all the places which is shown by this set of command.

```
import sys
sys.path
```

The file has a simple function something like this

```
 def hello(var):
     print("Hello "+var)
```

But when I run it

```
hello("Google")
```

I am getting NameError.

Please can anybody help me? I am using Windows. Or is it that I have to call by file name and not by function name? If so, how should I call it? 
Thanks in advance to whoever helps me.

Comment: How do you run the code? Do you have a script in a file (e.g., `script.py`) and you run it by typing `python script.py`?

Comment: You can't call a function from another file without importing it. `sys.path` is merely a list of all the places that the interpreter looks for names used in `import` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `import` your file first:

```
import myModule
```

(assuming your file is called `myModule.py`)

Then you can call the function like this:

```
myModule.hello('world')
```

Alternative syntax:

```
from myModule import hello
hello('world')
```

Comment: make sure you have a __init__.py file in your folder, if your code is not on the Python path

Comment: And that only helps if the folder itself is there :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I am now stuck with another problem. I would like to create a own folder of mine.So, I typed as import myFolder\\myFile and then it was returning as SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character. Please can you help me with this also?

Comment: @user1190882 The syntax would be `from myFolder import myFile` or `import myFolder.myFile` (in the second case you'll have to refer to the `hello` function as `myFolder.myFile.hello`). Note that here the folder is treated the same way as the module. For this to work you need to create an empty file named `__init.py__` in `myFolder`.